# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' in Flutter DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a DataTable from a Map using the following code:

```
DataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                                          DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                                          DataColumn(label: Text('Address')),
                                          DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
                                          ],
              rows: dictRoute.entries
                            .map((e) => DataRow(cells: [
                                          DataCell(Text(camelize(e.value['name'].toString()))),
                                          DataCell(Text(e.value['address'].toString())),
                                          DataCell(Text(e.value['phone'].toString())),])).toList(),
            ),
```

The DataCells keep giving me the following error:
[image]

I have found that the issue is with the e.value[''] section, where it's saying that it's expecting an int. Why would it be expecting an int? When I print out just e.value I get something like this for each entry:

```
{email: homer@gmail.com, note: 13-208, name: homer simpson, address: 742 Evergreen Terrace, phone: +15555555555}
```

Comment: I think it happens because `e.value[]` is an `Array`, so you should pass an index (which is an `Int`. But you pass some string, `e.value['some string']`. I am not sure exactly because the provided code is too little

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this problem is that each entry's value is a **String** type, not a Map type.

You can try to convert it to JSON:

```
dictRoute.entries.map((e) {
  Map _ = json.decode(e.value);
  return DataRow(cells: [
    DataCell(Text(_['name'].toString())),
    DataCell(Text(_['address'].toString())),
    DataCell(Text(_['phone'].toString())),
  ]);
}).toList())
```

If that doesn't work, I hope you can provide the code for dictRoute.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Map.entries.map((e) => T)`, e is a MapEntry object, with Key and Value's types defined to the Map object.

As @hisam just said in comments, you probably set your Map's value to array so e.value is of array type, but you're passing a String key to it, which is not possible in arrays.

```dart
Map<String, List> map;

map.entries.map((e) {
  // Because map is a Map<String, List>, e is a MapEntry<String, List>
  // Which means e.key is String and e.value is a List
});
```

If you make sure e.value is a Map type, it shouldn't have problems.

Comment: e.value is a Map, except one field wasn't. Somehow a random key/value was being added to dictRoute that wasn't a Map and that was causing the error. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There was a stray key/value showing up in dictRoute that wasnt of type Map, and that was causing the error. dictRoute is a very big nested map, so i didn't see the random key/value pair that was being added. All fixed now.